# I am working on project euler 52 to practice my Python but I think I have misunderstood what the problem is

Tags: python

> It can be seen that the number, 125874, and its double, 251748, contain exactly the same digits, but in a different order.

> Find the smallest positive integer, x, such that 2x, 3x, 4x, 5x, and 6x, contain the same digits.

I took this to mean find the smallest x for which 2x, 3x, 4x, 5x, and 6x are all doubles, that is, the smallest x for which they all have the same digits at the same frequency.

This can't be right as for whatever x, 2x will always have one extra 2 than 3x which has one extra 3 than 4x, etc.

Comment: $2x$ will have an extra $2$ if $x$ has a $1$ in its decimal representation in such a place that is independent of other digits, similarly for $3x$. But $x$ does not necessarily have to have a $1$ in its decimal representation

Comment: Please credit the original source of all copied material, following our guidelines here: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Answer (score 1):

Given a positive integer $x$ let $n_x = \lfloor \log_{10} x \rfloor$ and let $x_0, x_1, \dots, x_{n_x} \in \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ,8 ,9\}$ such that $x = \sum_{i=0}^{n_x} 10^i x_i$.
Define the multiset $S(x) = \{x_0, x_1, \dots, x_{n_x} \}$.

The problem is asking for:
$$
\min x \quad\mbox{ s.t.}\\
S(x)=S(ix) \quad \forall i \in \{2,3,4,5,6\}; \\
x \in \mathbb{Z}; \\
x > 0.
$$